# How to upload Testcases along with Steps from Excel to RALLY DEV?

Tags: rally

I want to upload multiple TCs along with steps from Excel to Rally Dev tool.

Please help me.

Comment: You should write what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Rally Excel plugin that allows import/export functionality.
For more information see this [guide](http://help.rallydev.com/rally-add-excel-installation-user-guide) and import/export [video](http://help.rallydev.com/import-export-excel-addin).

In order to import test case steps you need to import test cases first, and then import the second object: Test Case Step. It has to be done in two phases, test cases first, and then test steps, where you specify the parent object test case.

If you have further questions contact Rally support.